# Stuck with a Integer Programming problem

Tags: linear-programming

I've tried hours and hours to model this problem but i didn't succeed. Can you help  me ?

> We want to realize n projects in the next T years. For each project, a
> profitability index pi is known, which expresses the expected final
> gain (in Euro) and a cost profile ai = (ai1, ai2, ..., aiT) for each
> year of the period considered. Moreover, in each year j of the period
> a budget of bj € is available. Which projects should be selected to
> maximize the expected profit while respecting budget constraints?
>
> **Assume that the projects have a duration of T '< T years. For each**
> **selected project, we also want to identify the start year.**

Sometime ago i succeeded in modeling the non-bold part of the problem, however if i try to add also the last requirement i dont understand what to change of my original formulation, that is :

$max \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_{i}x_{i}$

$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{ij}x_{i}=b_{j}$ , $j=1..T$

$x_{i}\in \left \{ 0,1 \right \}$  , $i=1..n$

Comment: I do not see how time affects the problem. How does $a_i$ interact with the start year and duration?

Comment: If i start the project at year 10 and the project last for 4 years, then the cost in the 10-th year is a1, the cost in the 11-th year is a2 and so on until year 13

Comment: use a binary variable $x_{it}$ to indicate that project $i$ starts at time $t$

Comment: Nice ! Now what i dont understand is how to handle the budget every year (if i starta project start at year 2 , all the ai are shifted by 2 from the initial year ( that is 0))